# etree.tostring give strange symbol for text with "»"

Tags: python-2.6, elementtree

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lxml import etree

def str_repr(el, enc='utf-8'):
    doctype = ''
    text = etree.tostring(el, pretty_print=True, method='html', encoding=enc)
    text = doctype+text
    return text

def clear_scripts(text):
    parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    tree = etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(text), parser)

    return str_repr(tree.getroot())

text = '''»'''

text_final  = clear_scripts(text)
```

The problem is that there is no just sybmol `»` in text_final, but `Â»` (full line is `<html><body><p>Â»</p></body></html>`

Why is it so? How to leave just symbol `»`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the HTML parser, it does not know what encoding to parse the text with and does not default to UTF-8. You can fix this by replacing

```
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
```

with

```
parser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
```

You will also want to tell the browser about this too, if you view the output of your script as HTML, you will still see garbled text in many browsers since they do not expect utf-8 by default. Your generated HTML should contain a `head` section like the following:

```
<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
```

Answer (score 0):

text should be unicode string

```
text = u'»'
```